# Predicting CSAT scores using GAM

Tags: r, nonlinear-regression, ordinal-data, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

I am trying to fit a GAM model to predict CSAT (customer satisfaction scores on a scale of 0 to 10) which I believe are ordinal in nature. I used a categorical predictor (type) and two numeric predictors (duration, difference) which I believe have non-linear relationship to csat scores.

```
  gam_model = gam(
  csat_score ~ type + s(duration) + s(difference),
  family = ocat(R = 11), # since we have 11 possible values i.e. 0 to 10
  data = train_data)
```

However the above code throws error, which I couldn't figure out. I checked my data and it does have responses from 0 to 10 (all 11 of them are present) . No variables have missing values or outliers.

```
Error in eval(family$initialize) : values out of range
```

Structure of the dataset is as below:

```
csat_score : num [1:200] 8 9 9 9 10 ...
type : Factor w/ 4 levels "A","B".. 
duration : num [1:200] 3.75 3.75 4.52 ...
difference : num [1:200] -3.75 -3.75 -2.98 -5.25 ...
```

Can you please help me with :

1. Is this the right approach to predict CSAT scores using GAM ?
2. Why am I getting this error & how can I fix it?
3. Should I convert the response variable (csat_score) to categorical type?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `?mgcv::ocat`:

> The observed categories are coded 1, 2, 3, ... up to the number of categories.

I presume you used the CSAT scores *as is* (i.e. including a 0), which is not what is required for this model/family.

You shouldn't convert this response to be a factor; it needs to be an integer.

Comment: Thank you @Gavin. That worked once I changed the categories to 1 to 11.